# Is there any oracle compatible with ChainlinkClient v0.8 in Kovan?

Tags: oracle, chainlink

when I tested my smart contract in Kovan, the oracle (0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8) listed in [Contract Addresses](https://docs.chain.link/docs/decentralized-oracles-ethereum-mainnet/) failed to fulfill my request.
As I checked the failed [transaction](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xa012adf4094fe8a74c6040d41ae7bd2f09535e424691ff8f03bdb56fb9210a3e), I've found out that the signature in the InputData was `fulfillOracleRequest2` whereas other successful transactions' InputData contained `fulfillOracleRequest`. So the root cause of the issue seems to be the discrepancy between ChainlinkClient's version(v0.8) and the oracle's version.

Does anybody know of any oracle compatible with ChainlinkClient v0.8 in Kovan?

I've basically gone through the [official tutorial](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) to `Use Any API` except for the version of ChainlinkClient(The tutorial noted v0.6 but I used v0.8).

Comment: I just tested doing this, and it worked for me. Perhaps you can add your code you used to deploy?

Comment: Thank you @PatrickCollins! Actually, I could solve the issue when reproducing it.
By updating `@chainlink/contracts` from `0.1.7` to `0.2.1` (and by adjusting the path to ChainlinkClient.sol), my requests started to get fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By updating `@chainlink/contracts` from `0.1.7` to `0.2.1` (and by adjusting the path to ChainlinkClient.sol), my requests started to get fulfilled.